# Nested text view in android,with dynamic content

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I want to display a recursive or nested text view at depth of 3 in Android.The text to be displayed is, **dynamic** coming from web service.

```
for example: 
            If I Click on Help(Level 1)
               it'll show topics under Help
            If I Click on Help_Topic_1(Level 2)
               it'll show questions under Help_Topic_1  
            If I click on this question, say HT_Question_1(Level 3)
               it'll show Answer of that question(Level 3)
```

how to accomplish with this? please guide me.

Comment: no. at first i'll have List view, one of the list item will be Help, this should display above stated nested lists

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExpandableListView`. Reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

You can call `expandGroup` and `collapseGroup` methods for expanding and collapsing on clicks.

Comment: I followed link- http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/                                                                   I got exception  : Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Edit you question and add the xml layout and `onCreate` code.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do this is to have a nested layout structure.  Your root view will contain the button to show level 1 and a child layout and initially be visible.  The children's layout visibility will initially be set to "GONE".  In the onclick listener for each button you change the visibility of the layout below it to view to "VISIBLE".

This of course is a very simple way of doing it.  If you require to have open and close animations you'll need to use a more complex method.